# Matching data on String with data in the db in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a web application using Ruby on Rails and I have the following table :

```
  create_table "report_tags", force: true do |t|
   t.integer  "report_id"
   t.string   "tag",          limit: 20
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

So if a report with `report_id : 2` has the `tags : tag1, tag2` then this table will have two entries in order to describe this situation.

The user gives me as input a String which contains a lot of tags separated by comma or space and what I need to do is to find out if these tags are already contained inside a report.

From my experience in Java I would create a `List` with the tags parsed from the String (which I get from the user) and a `Map<int,List>` which would contain each report_id and the list of tags that it has after a query in the database. Then I would try to find out if any of the `lists in the Map` is the same with the `List` containing the tags.

I am now getting into Rails and since Rails offer a simpler way of doing things I was wondering :

Is there another simple *Ruby on Rails* way to do this comparison ??

Comment: Ruby has a built-in [`Set`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) class to store this sort of thing, as a starting point.

Comment: Checkout this [episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields) of Railscast.

Comment: the another good way you can use serialize to store array in db: http://amberonrails.com/storing-arrays-in-a-database-field-w-rails-activerecord/